# How to put all the variables in a single inspector header

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to put some variables under a header(within the **MonoBehaviour** class, I don't want to make another **editor** class).

When I write the variables in **a single line**, each one of them gets its own header:

```
[Header("Header")]
public int variable1, variable2;
```

[image]

So I have to write them in **individual lines**:

```
[Header("Header)"]
public int variable1;
public int variable2;
```

[image]

Can I achieve the second result with putting the variables in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could do this, but of course it's not the same:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Header header;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Header
{
    public int variable1, variable2;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be

```
[Header("Header)"]
public int variable1; public int variable2;
```

This is technically one line and Unity should treat them the way you wanted, though it is probably still not your desired way to declare variables